# Force required to crop/cut a mild steel bar

Tags: forces

I have cropping wedges with a diameter of 4mm cutting either side of a round mild steel bar (17.5mm). These wedges are operated using 2 hydraulic cylinders (6" diameter, 2 1/2 travel) (one for each cutting wedge) to force them against the mild steel. The cropping wedges are made from BS 970 304S12 steel.

Please can you help me determine the force required to crop this round bar and the formula used.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you explain what a "cropping wedge" is, and how something with a diameter of 4 mm is supposed to cut something with a 17.5 mm diameter? You are venturing into the realm of engineering (for which we have another SE site); if you want a physics answer you need to formulate as a physics question...

Comment: The tools required to cut steel of a given diameter are all listed in machine shop engineering handbooks. If you don't have one of these handy in the shop and/or if you don't know how to use them then you should probably not be operating tooling machines to begin with.

Comment: My apologies. Floris - the cutting edge of the wedge is 4mm thick, the wedge however has a width of greater than the round bar. The equipment is two wedges being driven together with the round bar in the middle. Similar to the operation of a bolt cutter. I cannot find the formula required to calulate the hydraulic force required to cut the round bar. Curious one - the machine has already been installed and the pressure delivered by the pump is sufficient. For part of my college course i would like to find the exact pressure required. Thank you